# Send values into method in VueJS 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

How can I get the values of `row.question_id` and `option.AnswerMasterID` in the method `selectChange` in the below code? I am using Vue.js v2.

```
<div v-if="row.answer_input_type === 'Dropdown'">
  <template v-for="answer in answers">
    <template v-if="answer.AnswerTypeID === row.answer_type_id">
      <select class="dropdown_cl" v-bind:disabled="row.is_enabled == 1 ? false : true" @change="selectChange(row.question_id, answer.AnswerDescription)">
        <option v-for="option in answer.AnswerDescription" v-bind:value="option.AnswerMasterID"   >{{option.AnswerDescription}}</option>
      </select>
      <p v-for="option in answer.AnswerDescription">{{option.AnswerMasterID}}</p>
    </template>
  </template>
</div>
```

My method is as follows:

```
selectChange: function (question_id, ans_master_id) {
  alert(question_id + " " + ans_master_id)
},
```

I want to get the value of `option.AnswerMasterID` which is in the inner loop.

Comment: What you exactly mean ?  Since you passed 2 parameters into `selectChange` method, you should allow your method to accept them
`selectChange(id, desc) { console.log(id, desc)}` and It would log the data what's passed when method is fired.

Comment: Look ok. What is the question about?

Comment: I want the value of option.AnswerMasterID

Comment: and you can get them in way I explained...

Answer (score 1):

Use a `v-model` directive on the select element to bind a data property to it:

```
<select class="dropdown_cl" v-model="selectedID" ...
```

Make sure you add `selectedID` to the data properties:

```
data() {
  return {
    selectedID: null,
  }
}
```

Since you are already binding `option.AnswerMasterID` as the value of each option, `selectedID` will be bound to the `AnswerMasterID` of the selected option.

You can then reference that value like this in your `selectChange` method:

```
selectChange: function (question_id) {
  alert(question_id + " " + this.selectedID);
},
```

[Here is Vue's documentation for select input binding.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select)

Comment: this works but I have different values for each select and the first option value for each is different. So if I write selected : ' ' and v-model="selected" then I am getting blank as the selected element for all the select elements. How to solve this?

Comment: @sagarmajumdar That sounds like a different question, which I think you've already posted?